# Is there anything wrong with using a 3 degree router bit to make a bevel?

Tags: router-bit, bevels

There was a question asked on reddit recently from someone that was trying to create a bevel on a door for as little money as possible which was accompanied by a lot of hate/negative feedback.

After watching this carpenter use a 3 Deg. router bit to make a bevel here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUNRI-UpSvw

It seems this could be a perfectly acceptable way to make a quick bevel in a tight spot. After I did a bit more digging around I found a bit that looks exactly like the one the content creator used in the video above.

*Carbide Tipped Patternmakers 3 Deg x 3/4 Dia x 2-1/8 x 1/2" Shank.*

[image]

Essentially this bit can handle any door up to 2 and 1/8 inches.
I decided to do a bit more digging around and actually called the company that designed this router bit to ask what they thought about using this to create the 3 deg bevel for a door. They told me the only thing that would really be required would to place a piece of wood under the door. So that the wheel can spin on that instead of spinning on the actual side of the door to get the full 3 degrees required.

Can anyone think of a reason why this is not an acceptable method to create a 3 degree bevel for a door allowing it to swing freely into its frame?

Comment: What method did Reddit haters say was better???

Comment: Traditional methods. Special saws and rails that cost hundreds to thousands. What else?

Comment: *"Special saws and rails that cost hundreds to thousands."* Well that's just, stoopid :-D As for the traditional methods, sure, I'm all in favour IF you have a hand plane already.... but then I'd imagine if the OP on Reddit had one he wouldn't have asked the question in the first place \*le sigh* P.S. straightedge (which can even be built on a strip of flippin' hardboard) and circular saw = most of the functionality of a track saw, as we have addressed here in a few previous Q&As.

Comment: "Special" saws and rails are not "traditional" for sizing doors, that's for sure. This word "taditional" can, for many meanings of the word, actually often translate to "frugal". You would hang your doors to the best of your skill using the tools available to you at the time.

Comment: Also, if I may offer some unasked-for advice, it would be stop using Reddit for _anything_. It is literally the worst of the web on any subject. If the internet is the tragedy of the commons, then Reddit is the prime example of how to boost noise well over the signal. Only the dumbest things, by and large, get amplified on Reddit.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. This kind of thing is what router bits _do_.

Comment: Wow! This question made it to the HNQ list! ---> _I wonder what the last [woodworking.se] question on the HNQ was?_

Comment: @FreeMan, we've actually been represented in the HNQ sidebar I think thrice this month. And yes, I'm as shocked as you are :-D

Comment: heh... maybe I should pay more attention to the HNQ listing... :)

Comment: @jdv, while I kinda want to agree on Reddit in general there are a few practical subs with enough solid, dependable members that you can get good info and feedback on things. Woodworking is one of those, but the signal/noise ratio is going to wax and wane over time.... as it does on almost any forum — I recently read a couple of old threads on a few traditional fora (including FW's, UKW and SMC, which I believe are broadly considered to be dependable) and I regret to say they were excellent examples of how the consensus view can be horribly poor.

Comment: To everyone wondering, this was the post: https://www.reddit.com/r/woodworking/comments/syxkk6/which_router_bit_makes_a_3_degree_bevel_that_i/

It seems that after the OP got 2 responses that had nothing to do with answering his question (which is very common with reddit, no one really answers your question), he was frustrated and asked for help in finding a place that could answer his question, which was met with even more hate.

Comment: You can read the suggestions given from the post, table saw, hand plane, Rip saw. Anyone that did suggest the bit I posted in my question, was ignored. Honestly, this is what reddit has become, a left wing, reactionary, mob rule, group of child. Even the adults act mostly like children. Basically Lord of the Flies with Ralph as sub moderator.

Comment: I mean, in my house it was _definitely_ hand-fit with plane installation. Never underestimate a pro's eye and thumb for getting a Good Enough fit on something that has to be custom fit anyway -- it's not like the jambs in my house were laser square either.

Comment: And, present company excluded, seeing how _awful_ the internet turned out from when I was a young politicized whippersnapper who was sure the internet (this was after ARCHIE and MUDs and before WWW) was going to free us all from corporate interests and save us from our own backwards tendencies... well, let's just say I have a rather dim view of most of what we call the internet these days. Now I will go outside and yell at the clouds.

Comment: In conclusion, Reddit is wrong. Again. _Qu'elle surprise_.

Comment: "... to make a bevel [on a door]?" - I was going to say, what the hell you using a 3 degree bevel for? Pretty much that, and only that, because that's not much of a bevel.

Comment: Running the bearing on the last little bit of the door would produce the same functional outcome as running the cutter completely on the door.

Comment: "Everything you read on the internet is true." -- Abraham Lincoln, 1863

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone think of a reason why this is not an acceptable method to create a 3 degree bevel for a door allowing it to swing freely into its frame?

I don't understand Reddit reaction. Cutting bevel on edge of board or panel is what such bits are for!

Maybe some objections are based on specific design of door where nails are known to be used, but for traditional door construction only one "gotcha" I can think is breakout at end of cut. This is easy to avoid by using climb cut for last 2" (5cm) or clamping on sacrificial piece to support edge of board.

Comment: This is the huge difference between stack exchange and reddit. Here, you actually get your questions answered, over there..... Not so much.

Comment: My biggest concern was the fact that this was maybe the only easy-to-buy bit I found, and it was  extremely expensive. On top of that, this bit was not designed for beveling doors, and the tech on the phone was kinda shocked I would even suggest using it for such a purpose, but agreed it should work.

Comment: I've never used a router to put a bevel on a door...and don't own such a specialized bit, but it seems pretty natural to me...if I already owned one. The guy on youtube makes it look easy.

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech but doors are just special kind of panel.... :)

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech, well as far as that goes, many tools are used for more than their original designed use. There are actually numerous other good examples amongst router bits, where only portions of the cutting edge are frequently used to create custom edge treatments or profiles, or the combination of multiple simple bits to replicate a complex moulding (very common in workshops without a spindle moulder). [contd]

Comment: Anyway, did the guy on the phone give you an indication of what the bit *was* made for? I was not previously aware of these prior to the Q but FWIW I can only think of two applications myself, and one of them would be to put a bevel on a door ^_^ (The other relates to moulding/casting, but I can't imagine that's it because the cutting length seems much longer than would be commonly required.)